# Make soundcloud playlist keep playing on reload

Tags: javascript, html, audio, soundcloud, html5-history

I have a Soundcloud playlist that autoplays on every page of my website. How can I make it continue playing when the page reloads?

Answer (score 0):

You could set a variable between sessions using local storage and retrieve this on page load.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage